# Stage shifts when I set offset

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, kineticjs

I am using KineticJs in my project. I am implementing zoom using mousewheel and buttons. For wheel zoom, the zoom should happend from the mouse pointer which is working fine. But for button zoom it should happen from the center of the `stage`. I am doing this:

```
var width = $(document).width() - 2,
    height = $(document).height() - 5;
//... a helper object for zooming
var zoomHelper = {
    stage: null,
    scale: 1,
    zoomFactor: 1.1,
    origin: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    zoom: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var delta;
        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
            if (event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                //scroll down
                delta = 0.2;
            } else {
                //scroll up
                delta = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                //scroll down
                delta = 0.2;
            } else {
                //scroll up
                delta = 0;
            }
        }
        var evt = event.originalEvent,
            mx = evt.clientX - zoomHelper.stage.getX(),
            my = evt.clientY - zoomHelper.stage.getY(),
            zoom = (zoomHelper.zoomFactor - delta),
            newscale = zoomHelper.scale * zoom;
        zoomHelper.origin.x = mx / zoomHelper.scale + zoomHelper.origin.x - mx / newscale;
        zoomHelper.origin.y = my / zoomHelper.scale + zoomHelper.origin.y - my / newscale;
        zoomHelper.stage.setOffset({
            x: zoomHelper.origin.x,
            y: zoomHelper.origin.y
        });
        zoomHelper.stage.setScale({
            x: newscale,
            y: newscale
        });
        zoomHelper.stage.draw();
        zoomHelper.scale *= zoom;
    }
};

var zoomIn = function (e) {
    zoomHelper.scale += .10;
    zoomHelper.stage.setScale({
        x: zoomHelper.scale,
        y: zoomHelper.scale
    });
    zoomHelper.stage.draw();
};

var zoomOut = function (e) {
    zoomHelper.scale -= .10;
    zoomHelper.stage.setScale({
        x: zoomHelper.scale,
        y: zoomHelper.scale
    });
    zoomHelper.stage.draw();
};

$(function () {
    var stage = zoomHelper.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        draggable: true
    });


    //it shifts the stage
    zoomHelper.stage.setOffset({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
    });
    //setting the position back....
    zoomHelper.stage.setPosition({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: '#E4E4E4'
    });

    var box1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        radius: 50,
        fill: '#00D200',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });

    var center = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2,
        radius: 5,
        fill: '#00D200',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });

    var box2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    box1.on('mouseover', function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    box1.on('mouseout', function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    // add cursor styling
    box2.on('mouseover', function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    box2.on('mouseout', function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    layer.add(background);
    layer.add(box1);
    layer.add(box2);
    layer.add(center);
    stage.add(layer);




    $(stage.content).on('wheel DOMMouseScroll', zoomHelper.zoom);
    $('#in').on('click', zoomIn);
    $('#out').on('click', zoomOut);
});
```

When I use the `stage.setOffset` method, the stage shifts. I don't know why this is happening. To solve this, as a workaround I set the position of it. But after doing all this when I do mouse zoom for the first time, stage shifts from it's actual position. After that everything works fine. I don't know what I am missing. I have created [fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_kumar/tr9ovtdk/). Please help. Thank you

Comment: I think after commenting this code

zoomHelper.stage.setOffset({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
    });
    //setting the position back....
    zoomHelper.stage.setPosition({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
    });
works fine. just check

Comment: It works fine but it doesn't zoom the floor map from center when I zoom using zoom buttons.

Comment: Please create a fiddle if you can make it working from center.